# Not Redirecting to 404 page with laravel give error if put wrong Url

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

**Hy!**
i'm using laravel 5.8 and when i put the wrong address in my url it give error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\post.blade.php)
```

**url like**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/lkfajds;

this is wrong url i put.

why this not back me to 404 page how can i do this

**Want:** i want to it redirect me to 404 page

Here htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use firstOrFail() on the model so it can show you the 404 page.

Comment: Method Illuminate\View\View::Fail does not exist. it give me this error

Comment: Not on the view. If you are searching for something into a model you can use that.https://laravel-news.com/laravel-firstorfail-forthewin

Comment: one more thing if i want to create my own 404 so how can i redirect this

Comment: In views you need to create a folder name "errors", and in there you can add the  name of the error page like follow: 404.blade.php